# System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

so basically at work I was assigned an old ASP.NET project which is outdated I have couple of months debugging it. Last week the project was working fine then from one moment to another stopped working. When I run the project I get this exception

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: 'An error
> occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the
> connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is
> correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used
> to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
> DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
> failure.'

Which also have 2 inner exceptions

> ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
> ProviderManifestToken string.
>
> OracleException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
> ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment
> specified

**What is causing this error?**

When I run the project I have a method called `LoadUserInfo();` which displays the user code, user department and username to retrieve this data, the application goes to the oracle database and retrieves this info, but for some reason (that I cant figure out) is not working.

[image: the method]

Comment: Did you checked the Connection to the Oracle Database?

Comment: Yes, I have checked eveythin related with the connection string, tables, etc..

Comment: Did you upgraded some nuget package or something?  All the errors points in the same, you lost connection  to your Database ... an update to entity so the context needs some new parameter, change in ssl certificate required or not, ...

Comment: I haven't updated any nuget, like I said the project was working 2 weeks ago and all of the sudden Im getting this error.